# Доступ для пользователей

Tags: html

Можно ли создать пользователей с паролями для доступа и редактирования только им по отдельности предоставленных страниц в html u css? Если да то как? И с помощью чего лучше?

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы и нет.
Скелет решения:

1. В базе таблица профиля юзера, где есть поля, указывающие директорию хранения их html и css файлов (я бы лучше папки разделил).
2. Ищем любой онлайн HTML CSS редактор (бесплатных много) и прикручиваем их к скриптам, отвечающих за редактирование файлов.

Как-то так.